# Change the app-name sent by docker's syslog driver

Tags: docker, syslog, papertrail-app

I'm using [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/) to collect my Docker container's logs.
Do to that, I used the syslog driver when I created the container:

```
sudo docker run --name my_container --log-driver=syslog  ...
```

... and added the following line to my `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
*.* @logsXXX.papertrailapp.com:YYYY
```

At the end, I get on Papertrail logs like this:

```
Apr 24 13:41:55 ip-10-1-1-86 docker/3b00635360e6: 10.0.0.5 - - [24/Apr/2015:11:41:57 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "" "-"
```

The problem is that the app-name (see [syslog RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424)) is **docker/container_id**

I would rather have the container name (or host). But I don't know how to do.
I tried to set a specific hostname to my container like below, but it didn't work better:

```
sudo docker run --name my_container -h my_container --log-driver=syslog  ...
```

Comment: Hopefully in docker v1.8 there will be a `--log-opt` option that could give you what you need. Source: http://blog.treasuredata.com/blog/2015/07/07/collecting-docker-logs-with-fluentd

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do it. Here's a pending PR to add that feature: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/12668

Hopefully it gets merged in soon. You could always roll your own, I suppose.

**Update**: Looks like this is slated for Docker 1.8

**Update**: This is now possible:

```
docker run --name my_container --log-driver=syslog --log-opt syslog-tag=my_application
```

Comment: *note:* it's now "tag" and not "syslog-tag": https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#/syslog-options